# Fill screen with div

Tags: html, css, frontend, shopify

How can I get my site to look like this? Where the first section fills the whole screen, then when you scroll down ANOTHER section fills the whole screen. https://pharmacy.cargo.site/ [image]

I tried doing a width/height 100%, but no luck. I tried styling an entire div with a background color, also no luck.

Comment: You can utilize viewport units (specifically `vh`) for that. Try setting `height: 100vh;` for a section. 1vh is 1% of the viewport's height. More info about viewport units can be found on [MDN CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Comment: Keep in mind that `vh` can be troublesome with mobile-devices due to navigation and scroll bars etc. sometimes rounding errors. You could try with the innerHeight of the window to find the best fit for the container height. For mobile, there is also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env

Comment: Dynamic viewport units are supported in all major browsers. `dvh` is the way to go: https://caniuse.com/?search=Small%2C%20Large%2C%20and%20Dynamic%20viewport%20units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full view scroll construction you need to:

- make sure that `html` and `body` consume the full viewport space available
- create a scroll container that fills that space and overflows to get a scrollbar (`.scroll-container`)
- create scroll container child elements that fill the parent (`.scroll-container > section`)

Optionally you can introduce [CSS Scroll Snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts) for full container scrolling (read 'full page' in your case).

**snippet**

```css
/***************************/
/* a few preferred globals */
/***************************/
* { box-sizing: border-box }
body,h1,h3 { margin: 0 } /* remove default HTML spacing */

/********/
/* DEMO */
/********/
/* Fill full viewport widht and height */
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100% }

.scroll-container {
    /* full screen scroll container */
    width : 100%;  /* full available width */
    height: 100vh; /* DEMO full viewport height */
    /* for scroll snap any 'height' is [MANDATORY] */

    /* [MANDATORY] for scroll snap */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y proximity; /* or 'mandatory' */
}

/* Generic content sections */
.scroll-container > section {
    /* Fill full scroll container  */
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    padding: 1rem;

    /* [MANDATORY] for scroll snap */
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

/* Specific section colors */
.one    { background-color: #eeeadf }
.two    { background-color: #c3d4c4 }
.three  { background-color: #d4c3d3 }

/*******************/
/* Extra eye-candy */
/*******************/
/* Fixed footer demo */
.fixed  {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    right: 17px; /* avoid overlaying scrollbar */
    background-color: hsl(0,0%,0%,.05);
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
.fixed h3 { text-align: right }
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
    <section class="one"  ><h1>section one  </h1></section>
    <section class="two"  ><h1>section two  </h1></section>
    <section class="three"><h1>section three</h1></section>
 </div>
 <footer class="fixed"><h3>fixed footer</h3></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you view the page source on the "Nested Scrollers" link below you can see the implementation of `vh` as mentioned by wouch.

```
        .screen {
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            min-height: 900px;
```

They are also using scrollMonitor library, which can be found here: https://github.com/stutrek/scrollmonitor

See their demo for [Nested Scrollers](http://stutrek.github.io/scrollmonitor/demos/divInADiv.html). Your are not interested in the nested scrollers themselves, but the three sections that contain them.

Answer (score 0):

User @Leland pointed out `dvh` and indeed, it seems to work just fine - thanks for pointing that out. It was always annoying to work with `vh`.
Last time I checked this feature, it was not supported enough (see bug report for Safari 15.6 https://caniuse.com/?search=Small%2C%20Large%2C%20and%20Dynamic%20viewport%20units. Now it seems to be fine - unless you need to support IE11.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.section {
  height: 100dvh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.section h3 {
  font-size: 64px;
}

.section-a {
  background-color: wheat;
}

.section-b {
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section class="section section-a">
      <h3>A</h3>
    </section>
    <section class="section section-b">
      <h3>B</h3>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```